# Dojo connect event handler getting called multiple times

Tags: dojo, event-handling

I've a button in my HTML page and I'm using `dojo.connect()` to attach an `onclick` event handler for that `button`. I'm assigning this event handler after an ajax call is completed. I'm facing an issue in which the event hanlder is **getting called multiple times** when I click the button once.

If I invoke the method which assigns the event handler for the
same event on the same button, will handler get invoked twice for that event? Or dojo is smart enough to do it just once? 
for example,

```
var i=3;
while(i==0){
 dojo.connect(dojo.byId('mybutton'),'onclick','hanlderMethod');
 i--;
}
```

Will the `handlerMethod` be called three times if I click on "`mybutton`"

If that is true, then my problem is related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handlerMethod is not called multiple times. Only once per event. So only if you change the relation **(event,handler)** it should fire again. Here is an jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ktnab/

```
function test() {
alert("test");
}

function test2() {
alert("test");
}

dojo.connect(dojo.byId("btn"), "onclick", test);
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("btn"), "onclick", test);
```

Check out this interesting article on dojo connect.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-dojoconnect/index.html?ca=drs-

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and this got resolved when the event attachment was done outside the loop.

Regards,
namratha